# Ayuda con la concatenación SQL en Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Tengo la siguiente concatenación:

> sql = "INSERT INTO Usuario(id_usuario, nombre, apellido, genero, edad, email, password, pais, provincia) values" +
>                           "(" + id_us +"," + nombre_us + "'" + ", '" + apellido_us + "'" + ", '" + genero_us + "'" + ", '" + edad_us + "'" + ", '" + email_us + "'" + ", '" + pass_us + "'" + ", '" + pais_us + "'" + ", '" + provincia_us + "')";

Quisiera saber si está bien porque me da el siguiente error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Usuario has no column named nombre (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Usuario(id_usuario, nombre, apellido, genero, edad, email, password, pais, provincia) values(1,'v', 'v', 'Hombre', '15/Junio/2016', 'v@gmail.com', 'ffffffffff', 'Argentina', 'Buenos Aires')

He declarado la tabla de la siguiente manera:

> String sqlTablaUsuario = "CREATE TABLE Usuario(id_usuario INTEGER, " +
>               "nombre TEXT, " +
>               "apellido TEXT," +
>               "genero TEXT, " +
>               "edad TEXT, " +
>               "email TEXT, " +
>               "password TEXT, " +
>               "pais TEXT, " +
>               "provincia TEXT)";

También he probado lo siguiente:

> DatabaseHelper chelp = new DatabaseHelper(this,"Helping",null,1);
>           SQLiteDatabase db = chelp.getWritableDatabase();
>           String genero_us ="";

```
        int id_us = 1;
        String nombre_us = nombre.getText().toString();
        String apellido_us = apellido.getText().toString();
        String edad_us = fecha.getText().toString();
        String email_us = et_mail.getText().toString();
        String pass_us = et_contrasenia.getText().toString();
        String pais_us = sp_pais.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String provincia_us = sp_provincia.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (rg.isChecked()){
                genero_us = "Hombre";
            }else{
                genero_us = "Mujer";
            }

        ContentValues nv = new ContentValues();
        nv.put("id_usuario", id_us);
        nv.put("nombr", nombre_us);
        nv.put("apellido", apellido_us);
        nv.put("genero", genero_us);
        nv.put("edad", edad_us);
        nv.put("email", email_us);
        nv.put("pass",pass_us);
        nv.put("pais", pais_us);
        nv.put("provincia", provincia_us);

        db.insert("Usuario",null,nv);
        db.close();
```

Y me da el siguiente error:

> Error inserting password=vvvvvvvvvvvv id_usuario=1 pais=Argentina email=b@gmail.com apellido=b genero=Hombre provincia=Chaco nombre=b edad=12/Junio/2016
>                                                                                android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Usuario has no column named password (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Usuario(password,id_usuario,pais,email,apellido,genero,provincia,nombre,edad) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: si, esta mal, usa comillas simples dentro de las expresiones sql

Comment: me darias el ejemplo como seria con mi sentencia?

Comment: @NicolasSchmidt, agrega por favor como creas tu tabla. Me parece que en realidad no estas creando la tabla o la creación tiene un error.

Answer (score 1):

En el primer caso debió de crear la tabla sin el campo `nombre`, y luego lo agregó. Intenta en borrar la aplicación e instalarla de nuevo, así le vuelve a construir la base de datos.

En el segundo caso esta enviando `pass`:

```
nv.put("pass",pass_us);
```

cuando deberia ser `password`:

```
nv.put("password",pass_us);
```

por lo tanto le muestra el error

> ```
> table Usuario has no column named password
> ```

Answer (score 0):

El mismo mensaje de error te indica que la tabla Usuario no contiene una columna llamada apellido:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Usuario has no column
>   named nombre (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
>   Usuario(id_usuario, nombre, apellido, genero, edad, email, password,
>   pais, provincia) values(1,'v', 'v', 'Hombre', '15/Junio/2016',
>   'v@gmail.com', 'ffffffffff', 'Argentina', 'Buenos Aires')

Si revisamos el query la contiene:

> String sqlTablaUsuario = "CREATE TABLE Usuario(id_usuario INTEGER, " +
>   "nombre TEXT, " + "apellido TEXT," + "genero TEXT, " + "edad TEXT, " +
>   "email TEXT, " + "password TEXT, " + "pais TEXT, " + "provincia
>   TEXT)";

**debes asegurar que la Tabla se haya creado correctamente.**

En el siguiente error me parece que es el mismo detalle, seguramente la tabla no fue creada correctamente.

> Error inserting password=vvvvvvvvvvvv id_usuario=1 pais=Argentina
>   email=b@gmail.com apellido=b genero=Hombre provincia=Chaco nombre=b
>   edad=12/Junio/2016 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table
>   Usuario has no column named password (code 1): , while compiling:
>   INSERT INTO
>   Usuario(password,id_usuario,pais,email,apellido,genero,provincia,nombre,edad)
>   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Vamos a revisar como creas tu tabla...